# Graphhopper for server multiple routes at the same time

Tags: java, web-applications, graphhopper

I developed a Graphhopper webapp. But likely there is no posibility to calculate multiple routes at the same time (If you deploy a webapp multiple users wil ask a route at the the same time). Is there any solution to calculate multiple routes at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can calculate multiple routes at the same time. This was already ask and answered [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/296), let me know there if you need further assistance. You can just use the provided web module or our Directions API.

BTW: For anyone coming to this SO question e.g. from a search engine and seeking for alternative route calculation with GraphHopper then this is also possible [since 0.6](https://graphhopper.com/blog/2016/02/08/releasing-graphhopper-0-6/)